# TIdNotify.Notify() doesn't work when called from TIdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, indy, lazarus, indy10

I have a Lazarus console app where I have a simple `TIdTCPServer`. To be a thread safe app, I added `TLog.LogMsg()` (which uses `TIdNotify`).

The problem is, when I call this function from the main thread, the message appears on the console, but when it is called from the `OnExecute` or `OnConnect` event of `TIdTCPServer`, the message is not displayed.

Can you help me with this problem?

```pascal
program Srv;

{$I Synopse.inc}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils, CustApp, Generics.Collections, IdTCPServer, IdCustomTCPServer, IdContext, IdGlobal, Db, mORMot, mORMotSQLite3, IdSync, functions, SynCommons, SynSQLite3Static;

type

  { TMyApplication }
  TMyApplication = class(TCustomApplication)

   var IdTCPServer: TIdTCPServer;

   protected
    procedure DoRun; override;
    procedure ServerOnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure ServerOnExecute(AContext: TIdContext);

  public
    constructor Create(TheOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  type
    TLog = class(TIdNotify)
    protected
      FMsg: string;
      procedure DoNotify; override;
    public
      class procedure LogMsg(const AMsg: string);
    end;

{ TMyApplication }

    procedure TLog.DoNotify;
    var i:integer;
    begin
     writeln(FMsg);
    end;

    class procedure TLog.LogMsg(const AMsg: string);
    begin
      with TLog.Create do
      try
        FMsg := AMsg;
        Notify;
      except
        Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;

procedure TMyApplication.ServerOnExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TLog.LogMsg('test OnExecute'); // the message is not displayed
end;

procedure TMyApplication.ServerOnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
 TLog.LogMsg('connect');        // the message is not displayed
end;

procedure TMyApplication.DoRun;
begin

  TLog.LogMsg('test main 1'); //the message is displayed
  IdTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create;
  try
    //Server.Name := 'Server';
    IdTCPServer.ListenQueue := 15;
    IdTCPServer.MaxConnections := 0;
    IdTCPServer.TerminateWaitTime := 5000;
    IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.IP   := '0.0.0.0';
    IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.Port := 80;
    IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.IPVersion:=Id_IPv4;
    IdTCPServer.OnConnect := ServerOnConnect;
  //  IdTCPServer.OnDisconnect := ServerOnDiconnect;
    //Server.OnException := IdTCPServer1Exception;
    IdTCPServer.OnExecute := ServerOnExecute;
    IdTCPServer.Active := True;
    TLog.LogMsg('test main 2'); //the message is displayed

  finally
   // IdTCPServerCmd.Free;
  end;
  readln;

  // stop program loop
  Terminate;
end;

constructor TMyApplication.Create(TheOwner: TComponent);
begin

  inherited Create(TheOwner);
  StopOnException := True;

end;


destructor TMyApplication.Destroy;
begin
  IdTCPServer.Free;
  inherited Destroy;

end;

var
  Application: TMyApplication;
begin
  Application := TMyApplication.Create(nil);
  Application.Title := 'My Application';
  Application.Run;
  Application.Free;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread does not have a message loop to process `TThread.Synchronize()`/`TThread.Queue()` requests. It is blocked on `Readln()`. Since you are in a console app and not a GUI app, you need to manually call [`Classes.CheckSynchronize()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/checksynchronize.html) periodically in the main thread.

---

On a side note, you are calling `IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add()` too many times. In your example, you need to call it only 1 time, creating 1 binding that has the 3 property values assigned to it. But instead, you are calling it 3 times, creating 3 separate bindings with 3 separate property settings.  It should look more like this instead:

```pascal
with IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add do
begin
  IP := '0.0.0.0';
  Port := 80;
  IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
end;
```

Which can be simplified as `0.0.0.0` and `Id_IPv4` are already the default values, so they can be omitted from your code. And `TIdTCPServer` has a `DefaultPort` property you can use instead. The `TIdTCPServer.Active` property setter will create its own default bindings if there are none defined explicitly.